# Onedrive File picker not opening when using authorization code flow

Tags: ruby, url, oauth-2.0, authorization, onedrive

I am following the [Microsoft onedrive documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631818.aspx#authcodegrant)  authorization code flow to grant my user access to their onedrive files.

I got the access_code and sent a POST request using ruby with access_code, client_id, clien_secret and got the access_token as a JSON response.

when I try appending this access_token,scopes,state,.. along with My Redirect_url to access the Onedrive file Picker the window closes. The following is the sample URL of that

```
 http://MY_REDIRECT_URL/onedrive#access_token=My_access_token&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=wl.skydrive%20wl.signin&state=redirect_type%3dauth%26display%3dpage%26request_ts%3d1427963180884%26response_method%3durl%26secure_cookie%3dfalse&user_id=My_USER_ID
```

when I used the same URL in Authorization token flow it's properly opening  the file picker.
When I checked the wl_auth cookie value it's saying

```
 error=invalid_cookie&error_description=The%20'wl_auth'%20cookie%20has%20been%20modified%20incorrectly.%20Ensure%20that%20the%20redirect%20URI%20only%20modifies%20sub-keys%20for%20values%20received%20from%20the%20OAuth%20endpoint.&status=connected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that we need to make the URL the same as the URL that would be obtained when Authorization token flow is used.

Also, while making URL make sure its encoded and also response_type value should be URL not COOKIE